# How do I give :hover selection to other elements when I'm actually hovering on something other than the element I'm giving the style to?

Tags: css

Okay, so this is what I'm trying to achieve here.

I have this board that I'm trying to style, 
and when I hover over a `<tr>`, I want to give `color:#fff` to the `<a>` that's inside of the `<tr>` I'm hovering on.

It doesn't work if I give

```
tr:hover {color:#fff}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
I can't seem to find the right selector.

And here is the site I'm working on http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```css
tr {
  background: #eee;
}
tr:hover {
  background: #333;
}
tr:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```